# Why does this list become an int variable?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a Python code that takes a list and outputs the first *n* elements that are odd numbers (this is for an Intro to Python course).  There is a limitation on permissible methods, namely being **only** those that we have covered to this point, which in respect to this question would limit us to using `len`, `for loops` with `in`, `nested for loops`, `conditional statements`, `break`, etc (we have **not** covered `count`, `while`, list comprehensions, etc.  Note: my apologies if I'm not able to comprehensively enumerate that which we have yet to learn.

Here is what I've managed to arrive to:

```py
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]    
num_list2 = []

for num_list2 in num_list:
    if num_list2 % 2 != 0:
        if len(num_list2) < 5:
            append.num_list2()
        else:
            break
print(num_list2)
```

However, this returns a type error.  I'm not understanding why `num_list2` becomes an `int` type even though I've initialized it as an empty list?  Further, beyond the error itself,  I'm not sure whether this conditional logic is legal in Python to then ends of achieving what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: What do you think `for num_list2 in num_list:` does?

Comment: To my limited understanding, it executes a statement by iterating through the elements of the list `num_list`?

Comment: @Dai or am I mistaken?

Comment: Try using `for n in num_list` instead of `for num_list2 in num_list`, then spot the difference and try to understand why one works and not the other.

Comment: @Dai that returns error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'`.  I've also noticed I'm possibly got the append syntax the opposite of what it should be, but I'm just going to go through this one line at a time for now.

Comment: You assign to the variable `num_list2` before the loop: `num_list2 = []`. But then, you use `num_list2` as your looping variable, so on each iteration of the loop, the variable `num_list2` get's assigned the next element in the list, overwriting the list you had assigned initially. Why did you use that variable name as the loop variable? Was it just a mistake? It seems more likely you chose it on purpose to be the same, but why? In any case, *don't do that*. Just use any other variable that isn't used, e.g. `x`. `for x in num_list: ...`

Comment: OK, now in the body, how do you append this element to the list, `num_list2`, (now that it is a list, and it hasn't been overwritten by the int)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your helpful responses.  I'm honestly just running on fumes right now, I'm going to catch some sleep and revisit this tomorrow after I'm rested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use better variable names in order to avoid confusing yourself. Look at this slightly modified version:

```py
target_len = 5    
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
output = []
        
for item in num_list:
    if item % 2 == 1:  # modulo 2 can only yield 0 or 1
        output.append(item)
    if len(output) >= target_len:
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using two different purposes of `num_list2`.

1. A list that has (up to five) odd numbers. This is a **list**.
2. An element of `num_list` checked in an `if` statement whether it is odd or not. This is an **int**.
   Namely, in those lines.

```py
for num_list2 in num_list:
    if num_list2 % 2 != 0:
```

Change the occurrences of the second usage of `num_list2` to another variable.

---

**EDIT**: You seem to misunderstand what the for loop does.

```py
for num_list2 in num_list:
    if num_list2 % 2 != 0:
        if len(num_list2) < 5:
            append.num_list2()
        else:
            break
```

does the following:

```
if len(num_list) >= 1:
    num_list2 = num_list[0]
    if num_list2 % 2 != 0:
        if len(num_list2) < 5:
            append.num_list2()
        else:
            break

if len(num_list) >= 2:
    num_list2 = num_list[1]
    if num_list2 % 2 != 0:
        if len(num_list2) < 5:
            append.num_list2()
        else:
            break

if len(num_list) >= 3:
    num_list2 = num_list[2]
    if num_list2 % 2 != 0:
        if len(num_list2) < 5:
            append.num_list2()
        else:
            break


...
```

`num_list2` is reassigned an int value each time the for loop runs in your code.

Comment: To be frank, this is something that's been confusing to me from the onset and I'm still not clear on that point.  To me (the newly initiated), I'm confused when a variable gets used without a declaration (in fact, due to my lack of familiarity, I've had trouble discerning whether or not they are keywords at times).  In this case, changing the second occurrence to an arbitrary variable (such as `x`) results in a `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`.

Comment: @Arctiic Python doesn't have declarations. You simply assign to a variable, the simplest: `x = 42`, however, there are other statements that assign to variables, e.g. a for-loop statement, `for x in some_list: ...` will assign to `x` on each iteration

Comment: @Arctiic read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I chose @adam 's answer because it led me to the correct output, but I just wanted to make a point in stating that I appreciate both your answer, as well as the linked resource you provided.  Both were very informative, the linked resource being particularly so as it perfectly addresses exactly what confused me regarding Python's assignments.  Thank you for taking the time to share these!